# How to add ADFS Relying Party Trust SAMLAssertionConsumer using New-ADFSSamlEndpoint

Tags: powershell, adfs, adfs2.0

I'm trying to build a script with powershell that will ask for a new uri to be added to an existing list of Relying Party Trust SAML Assertion Consumer Endpoints.

I've used this:

```
$samlEndpoint1 = New-ADFSSamlEndpoint -Protocol 'SAMLAssertionConsumer' -Uri 'https://moo.mydomain.local/samlprp-0/' -Binding 'POST' -IsDefault $false -Index 3
        Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "ExistingRPT" -SamlEndpoint @($samlEndpoint1)
```

However this seems to remove the existing ones that are there and just leaves this new one. Therefore I was hoping this just added it to the existing list.
Does anyone please have any suggestions? Do I have to export the existing ones to some kind of array and then add to it?
Thanks for your time